# Saving inputs from form using viewModel from different Entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a view Model that displays all the info I need in my form.

As you can see below my `ViewModel` uses `CustomerEntities`. I want to save the information in a table that is using `CalendarEntities`. I was of the idea of having the Calendar have its own Entity outside of `Customer`, however I need to use `CustomerEntities` to retrieve information from the logged in user to put in the form. When I put the items in the `HttpPost`, it says that `CustomerEntities` does not include a definition for Events. Is there anyway to get around this without moving the Events out of its own entity and into CustomerEntities?

Here is the CalendarController

```
    private CalendarEntities customer = new CalendarEntities();

    private CustomerEntities db = new CustomerEntities();

    // GET: ServiceCalendar
    public ActionResult Index(string UserId)
    {
        if (UserId == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        AddEventViewModel modelInstance = AddEventViewModel.GetCustomerInfo(UserId, db);

        return View(modelInstance);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "CustomerId,CustomerName,AllDay,Location,Title,Description,StartDate,EndDate")] EventModels.Entities.Events calendarEvent)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Events.Add(calendarEvent);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(calendarEvent);
    }
```

Here is the viewModel

```
public class AddEventViewModel
{
    public static AddEventViewModel GetCustomerInfo(string userId, CustomerEntities db)
    {
        var QCustInfo = from ad in db.Addresses
                        join ua in db.UserToAddresses on ad.AddressId equals ua.AddressId
                        join cus in db.CustomerNames on ad.CustomerId equals cus.CustomerId
                        where (ua.UserId == userId)
                        select new AddEventViewModel
                        {
                            CustomerId = cus.CustomerId,
                            CustomerName = cus.CustomerName,
                            //Location = ad.LocationName,
                            CustomerNames = cus
                        };
        var result = QCustInfo.SingleOrDefault();

        if (result != null)
        {
            result.Addresses = db.Addresses.Where(a => a.CustomerId == result.CustomerNames.CustomerId);

        };

        return result;
    }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Location Name")]
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public bool AllDay { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime), Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime), Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "End Date")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Customer Name")]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public virtual CustomerNames CustomerNames { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Addresses> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I suppose I could get around this by using a stored procedure. That would work, however is it proper to mix Entity Framework with stored procedures. I have done this already in this project and it works. I just dont know if it is the right thing to do..

Comment: I created a Stored procedure to handle this for now, I will await a better solution, if there is one..

Comment: you can call ajax post method which helps to create own model while sending to controller and match it with your 2nd model

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by "Is there anyway to get around this without moving the Events out of its own entity and into CustomerEntities?"  Based on what you've shown it almost looks like you are creating one DbContext per entity, or per top-level entity which is really giving off a bad smell if these entities are part of the same database. A DbContext is not an entity, it is a container for many entities. For smaller systems it easily houses all entities, or at least all top-level entities that need to be directly queried.  The "entity" is the class that represents a row in a table within the database.

Normally I'd expect to see that if you are working with Calendars and Customers where a Calendar entry references a customer, and a set of events, that I'd have a CalendarEntry entity similar to:

```
public class CalendarEntry
{
    public int CalendarEntryId { get; private set; }
    // .. Other properties...

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; private set; }
    public virtual List<CalendarEvent> Events { get; private set; } = new List<CalendarEvent>();
}
```

With similar entity definitions for customer and events.

There would be one single DbContext that might have:

```
public DbSet<CalendarEntry> CalendarEntries { get; }
public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; }
```

View Models on the other hand are simple, POCO classes that have their data copied from entities, and do *not* contain entities.  The controller controls the scope of a DbContext to read entities, then Selects, or maps entity data into View Models to pass to the view. It receives view models from the view, loads entities, and modifies the entities based on the data in the view model.

So an action that receives a calendar event to be updated I would aim to have a method that took a view model to represent the new calendar event, including the ID of the calendar entry. The entry wouldn't be created on the Index of the calendar event, but rather before that, then the index simply displays the view model for the new entry. So perhaps on the Calendar Controller there would be an action to create a new event, that action would pass the CalendarEntryID, create the CalendarEvent view model on the entry and then redirect to the calendar event view. The ViewModel is a POCO, not an entity, nothing is committed to the database yet. In the CalendarEvent view there would be a Save button which accepts that view model and that controls when the entity is created...

```
public ActionResult Save(CalendarEventViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(viewModel);

    var calendarEntry = db.CalendarEntries.Include(x => x.Events)
        .Single(x => x.CalendarEntryId = viewModel.CalendarEntryId);

    var calendarEvent = new CalendarEvent
    {
        CalendarEntry = calendarEntry,
        EventName = viewModel.EventName,
        // .. etc.
    };
    calendarEntry.Events.Add(calendarEvent);
    db.SaveChanges(); 
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The difference here is that the view model(s) are completely independent of the entities that populate them. They represent the data that the view needs, and what the controller will need to locate the applicable entities, nothing more. You can leverage tools like Automapper to help copy details efficiently between entities and view models. Note that in this example the DbContext (db) did not reference a DbSet for CalendarEvents? The events are a child of the CalendarEntry and the context doesn't need a DbSet for every entity, just ones we care about querying directly. (top-level entities) I don't want separate DbContexts for each entity because you cannot leverage the relationships between entities. In this case, by CalendarEvent view model would have a CalendarEntry ID which I can use to locate the entry. I then populate the new entity for the Event from the rest of the view model's details, then add that new entry to event and call SaveChanges. EF is tracking changes made against the CalendarEntry that I loaded, which extends to the collection of events. I don't need to track a separate Events DbSet to add to the context.

Other things to consider is the scope of the DbContext (db). You want to ensure that the Context is injected into your controller and it's lifetime scope is limited to the life of the request. (Using an IoC container such as Autofac, Unity, etc.) you want to be very certain that it isn't Static or living longer than the request because this will lead to resource/performance issues, and potentially bugs/exceptions with concurrent requests.

Worst case, if you are not sure how the DbContext is scoped, or have it set up as Static, you should change its use to scope inside the method, then read up on Dependency Injection and IoC containers to scope it to the request and inject it with the constructor.

For example:

```
public ActionResult Save(CalendarEventViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(viewModel);

    using( var db = new myDbContext())
    {
        var calendarEntry = db.CalendarEntries.Include(x => x.Events)
            .Single(x => x.CalendarEntryId = viewModel.CalendarEntryId);

        var calendarEvent = new CalendarEvent
        {
            CalendarEntry = calendarEntry,
            EventName = viewModel.EventName,
            // .. etc.
        };
        calendarEntry.Events.Add(calendarEvent);
        db.SaveChanges(); 
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. I am not using separate entities for everything. I do use the context within my actions in most cases. I will make sure I fix the ones that dont. In this case I was thinking that since the calendar was not a direct customer related view, meaning not a personal calendar for the customer, that I would put it in its own folder with its own entity. The calendar is meant for customer to schedule "My Company" for service work. In the admin section I have all the control of the calendar and can see everything on it. where their view only shows a title.

Comment: I did not want customers across the board to see other entries, possibly competitors, names etc. so they only see the calendar view with a what is being done. Not where or who. This way they can see if a week is booked up and schedule for a different week. Hope this makes sense. I guess I could have put the dbset in the customer entities, just thought it made better sense to not too at the time. What even goes further with that, if you add a model from a table, it creates a separate entity for each. which contradicts what you are saying. Thanks again. This is only version 1. 2 will be cleanup!